# Can't get mod_python and web.py to work, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, web.py, mod-python

I didn't do the Apache setup for this it was done by the hosting company and apparently they don't know that much about Python and mod_python, so I'm stuck I only have access to a .htaccess file and my own code.

.htaccess

```
AddHandler python-program .py
PythonHandler wsgiref.modpython_gateway::handler
PythonOption wsgi.application code::main
```

code.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)

main = web.wsgifunc(web.webpyfunc(urls, globals()))

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'Pussy'
        return 'Hello, '+ name +'!'

#if __name__ == "__main__":
    #main = web.wsgifunc(web.webpyfunc(urls, globals()))
```

Error message I'm seeing when loading the code.py file

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      30954
Interpreter:    'example.dk'

ServerName:     'example.dk'
DocumentRoot:   '/var/www/example.dk/web'

URI:            '/code.py'
Location:       None
Directory:      '/var/www/example.dk/web/'
Filename:       '/var/www/example.dk/web/code.py'
PathInfo:       ''

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'wsgiref.modpython_gateway::handler'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/modpython_gateway.py", line 206, in handler
    app = getattr(module, objname)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

What am I missing? Im using http://webpy.org/deployment as a reference. Server environment

```
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64
```

Comment: Do you really have to use mod_python? That hasn't been the way to deploy Python apps on Apache for many years. Can you not use mod_wsgi?

Comment: You only define `main` if it is in the main interpreter scope (`if __name__ == "__main__":`) but the `code` module is being imported.

Comment: Daniel, mod_python is the only way with this hosting company. I could move away but they also run the mail server and other things I'd have to move as well

Comment: systemjack I changed it but still same error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Comment: webpy.org/deployment has a warning, "Be sure to visit /code.py/ with an extra / on the end. Otherwise you'll see an error message."

Comment: @pbuck I have tried that as well, same issue. The problem is elsewhere

Comment: @kristiannissen What OS version are you using? mod-python is so old I can't find a working test system.

Comment: @pbuck windows, I assume, since the host also provides ASPX